# Application of pigeonhole principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Select $11$ different numbers from $f\{1,2,...,20\}$. Prove that two of your numbers, $a$ and $b$, will differ by two.

Clearly this is an application of the pigeonhole principle. However, I'm not sure how to write up a coherent proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following sets: $$\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{5, 7\}, \{6, 8\}, \{9, 11\}, \{10, 12\}, \{13, 15\}, \{14, 16\}, \{17, 19\}, \{18, 20\}$$

Together, these $10$ sets account for all of the integers $\{1, \ldots, 20\}$. When we pick 11 numbers, by the Pigeonhole Principle, we will pick both numbers from at least one of the sets. Hence, these two numbers (which we can denote $a$ and $b$) will differ by two.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!